# Prevent Multiple Token Refreshes With API React Hook

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I have an API hook called `useAPICall` that has a callback `call`.  This callback checks if a token stored in a reactn variable called `auth` is expired, refreshes it if necessary, then calls the fetch function.

I call it in my component like this:

```
const [api] = useAPICall();

useEffect(() => {
    api.call('/api/settings/mine/').then(data => {
        // do stuff here
    });
}, []);
```

And it does work.  It goes through the authentication flow and calls the API.  But if I have `useAPICall` is multiple components that all try to call the API around the same time (such as a cold page load), then each instance of it calls the refresh token method because it's expired.

The auth info (access/refresh tokens) are stored in a reactn global variable `auth` such as below, inside the `useAPICall.js` hook

```
import React, {useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useGlobal} from 'reactn';


export function useAPICall() {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useGlobal('auth');
    const authRefreshSuccess = useDispatch('authRefreshSuccess');

    async function refreshToken() {
        console.log('Refreshing access token...');
        const authResponse = await fetch('/api/auth/token/refresh/', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify({refresh: auth.refresh.token}),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        if (authResponse.ok) {
            const authToken = await authResponse.json();
            await authRefreshSuccess(authToken);
            return authToken.access;
        }
    }

    function isTokenExpired() {
        if (localAuth.access)
            return auth.access.exp <= Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        else
            return false;
    }

    const call = useCallback(async (endpoint, options={headers: {}}) => {
        console.log('performing api call');
        token = undefined;

        if (isTokenExpired())
            token = await refreshToken();
        else
            token = localAuth.access.token;

        const res = await fetch(endpoint, {
            ...options,
            headers: {
                ...options.headers,
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            }
        });
        if (!res.ok)
            throw await res.json();
        return res.json();

    }, []);

    const anonCall = useCallback(async (endpoint, options={}}) => {
        const res = await fetch(endpoint, options);
        if (!res.ok)
            throw await res.json();
        return res.json();

    }, []);


    const api = useMemo(
        () => ({
            call,
            anonCall,
        }),
        [call, anonCall,]
    );

    return [api]
}
```

How can I prevent them from firing off the refresh method multiple times?

If there's a better way (without redux) to have a universal API flow (where any API call would first check access token and refresh if necessary), then I'm willing to listen.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do this by storing a promise in a global variable.

```
let refreshPromise = null;
    
export function useAuthentication() {
    
      async function getBearer() {
    
        if (isExpired(jwt)) {
          if (refreshPromise == null) {
            refreshPromise = refresh().then((jwt) => {
              refreshPromise = null;
              return jwt;
            });
          }
          await refreshPromise;
        }
    
        let authData = getAuthData();
        if (authData && authData.accessToken) {
          return `Bearer ${authData.accessToken}`;
        }
        return null;
      }
    
      const AuthenticationService = {
        getBearer,
        ...
      };
    
     return AuthenticationService;
}
```

Hope this helps !